# jquery position function/object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, uislider

I've seen this similar code on two sites now used in correlation with jquery slider

```
function reCenterButton() {
    $(".button").position({
        "my": "center center",
        "at": "center center",
        "of": $("#button-box")
    });
};
```

can someone tell me what the name/value pairs mean in the position function object

seen it here http://jsfiddle.net/william/RSkpH/1/
and here http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

I can't seem to find it when i look up documentation for the position() is it part of slider function?

Comment: Here's the documentation you need: [http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/).

Comment: @jakeclarkson Damn! ;) My answer tooks so long to write. Your comment was not there as i started answering :)

Comment: As long as we can consider copy-pasting documentation to be an answer...

Comment: @DidierGhys Sorry that i want provide the whole information. Not just a part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new in jQuery UI 1.8. You can use it for fast positioning.

> Utility script for positioning any widget relative to the window, document, a particular element, or the cursor/mouse.
>
> **my *(String)***
>
> Defines which position on the element being positioned to align with the target element: "horizontal vertical" alignment. A single value such as "right" will default to "right center", "top" will default to "center top" (following CSS convention). Acceptable values: "top", "center", "bottom", "left", "right". Example: "left top" or "center center"
>
> **at *(String)***
>
> Defines which position on the target element to align the positioned element against: "horizontal vertical" alignment. A single value such as "right" will default to "right center", "top" will default to "center top" (following CSS convention). Acceptable values: "top", "center", "bottom", "left", "right". Example: "left top" or "center center"
>
> **of *(Selector, Element, jQuery, Event)***
>
> Element to position against. If you provide a selector, the first matching element will be used. If you provide a jQuery object, the first element will be used. If you provide an event object, the pageX and pageY properties will be used. Example: "#top-menu"
>
> **offset *(String)***
>
> Add these left-top values to the calculated position, eg. "50 50" (left top) A single value such as "50" will apply to both.
>
> **collision *(String)***
>
> When the positioned element overflows the window in some direction, move it to an alternative position. Similar to my and at, this accepts a single value or a pair for horizontal/vertical, eg. "flip", "fit", "fit flip", "fit none".
>
> - **flip**  to the opposite side and the collision detection is run again to see if it will fit. If it won't fit in either position, the center option should be used as a fall back.
> - **fit** so the element keeps in the desired direction, but is re-positioned so it fits.
> - **none** not do collision detection.
>
> **using *(Function)***
>
> When specified the actual property setting is delegated to this callback. Receives a single parameter which is a hash of top and left values for the position that should be set.

#### More Information

- [jQuery - UI/API/1.8/Position](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position)

Comment: Thanks again... I did know it was part of the UI.  I'll have to play around with it when using my jquery slider

Answer (score 2):

jQuery UI Position provides a way to position elements relatively to the window, the document or another element.

Concerning the options:

- **of**: the element relatively to which the matched elements (on which .position() is called - `.button`) will be positioned
- **my**: the alignement rule that will be used for **the element being positioned** (`.button`)
- **at**: thr alignement rule that will be used for **the target element** (`#button-box`)

So in your example, the element `.button` will be centered with the element `#button-box`.

Another example:

```
$('#menu').position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'left bottom',
    of: '#selectMenu'
});
```

This could be used to position a custom dropdown widget. `#selectMenu` is "select" and `#menu` is the option list that appear when clicking the select.

This will position the option list right under the select.

[image]

Comment: A picture tells more than thousand words. Thanks @didier-ghys for your effort to pin it as a screen.